# a return keyword must not be followed by object expression

Tags: c#, methods

my code is running but the biggest number out of the three numbers that has been entered is not appearing how can I solve this?

## this is the code that I have done

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image.  So that it is easier to read, and copy-paste (if required).

Comment: Your method `GetMax` returns `void` yet you are trying to return an int (`a`).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There problem with your code is that the return type of `GetMax` is `void` meaning it does not return anything, and you try to return an integer.

You should make the following change:

```
static int GetMax(int first, int second)
-------^^^
{
    int a;
    if (first > second) a = first;
    else a = second;
    return a;
}
```

The second problem is that in the Main method you are just calling the `GetMax` method without doing anything with the max value.

So in main you should also change the following:

```
int max = GetMax(GetMax(a, b), c);

Console.WriteLine("The biggest number is", max);
```